# How do you create and execute a bash script which calls an executable from higher folder?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm attempting to write a very simple script which calls an executable from a higher level folder. If I were just typing the command into the console, I would type

```
../filenamehere {options} {parameters}
```

When I try to do the same thing in a .sh file in order to run multiple processes at the same time, I attempt to write the following:

```
../filename {options} {parameters} &
../filename {options2} {parameters} &
../filename {options3} {parameters} &
../filename {options4} {parameters} &
```

Then, to run the file, I entered

```
chmod a+x script_file.sh
./script_file.sh
```

After which point I was given a "command not found" error 3 times. I assume this means that 1 of my 4 commands executed, but the other 3 didn't. If I type directly into the console exactly the same commands as I put in the .sh file, nothing goes wrong. What do I need to do to make this file run?

Comment: Also, this is my first experience with bash and scripting. I have little to no experience with this and the tutorial articles I am reading as I do this are not very helpful.

Comment: I should work. Please post the script and a directory listing (`ls ..`).

Comment: I don't see any problem calling/executing script located in one directory level up:

$ cat a.ksh
../b.ksh
echo done

$ cat ../b.ksh
echo inside b.ksh

$ chmod a+x a.ksh ../b.ksh

$ a.ksh
inside b.ksh
done

You can try with absolute path while invoking also. What's the exact error?. And is this script from something like autosys job?, in which case it considers directory reference relative to autosys installed path

Comment: I have no idea what autosys is, or what the $ cat command you're using is about. The exact error is ":command not found1:" and then ":command not found2:" and ":command not found3:"

Comment: Are you sure that writing such a narrow-purpose script (i.e., one that works only from a specific folder) is such good style? Shoudn't you perhaps aim at something larger?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I'm just trying to write a script file at all. This is to keep me from having to type into the console ../filename {options} {parameters} repeatedly and then vary the options and parameters each time for the about 50 times I have to run the same executable (with different parameters). If you have an idea for something I should write instead, let me know... but for now I am doing this to learn how to write scripts in general...

Comment: Teofrostus, I hate to say this, but not knowing the `cat` command is kind of a red flag.  You should learn some Linux in general before trying to learn shell scripting; `cat` is pretty basic, and it's even used sometimes in scripting (for instance in displaying the script usage).  Start by studying some Linux for the sake of learning Linux, and go from there.  I recommend this free course: https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-2

Answer (score 2):

Are you using symlinks ?

To write reliable scripts, you should not be using "dirname $0". It relates to the $0 command, which is related to the calling command. If you are navigating across directories, use instead "readlink -f $0".

```
basedir="$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))"
$basedir/../filename {options} {parameters} &
```

`readlink -f` will give you the absolute path of your script, regardless of the link, workdir, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can try running your script with `pwd` before calling the executable to see if your script is changing the directory after running the first executable.

```
pwd
../filename {options} {parameters} &
pwd
../filename {options2} {parameters} &
pwd
../filename {options3} {parameters} &
pwd
../filename {options4} {parameters} &
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm just doing something horribly wrong. Including pwd in my .sh file, i get ": command not found 1: pwd", with a change in the line number for each pwd command...

Comment: can you post your script here?

Comment: Here it is exactly: 

../sim-outorder -fetch:ifqsize 1 -issue:width 1 -decode:width 1 -commit:width 1 cc1.alpha -O 1stmt.i > 1inst-cc1.std 2> 1inst-cc1.stat &
../sim-outorder -fetch:ifqsize 2 -issue:width 2 -decode:width 2 -commit:width 2 cc1.alpha -O 1stmt.i > 2inst-cc1.std 2> 2inst-cc1.stat &
../sim-outorder -fetch:ifqsize 4 -issue:width 4 -decode:width 4 -commit:width 4 cc1.alpha -O 1stmt.i > 4inst-cc1.std 2> 4inst-cc1.stat &
../sim-outorder -fetch:ifqsize 8 -issue:width 8 -decode:width 8 -commit:width 8 cc1.alpha -O 1stmt.i > 8inst-cc1.std 2> 8inst-cc1.stat &

Comment: For some reason, I can't make the lines show up separately... But each ../ is on it's own line. There's a total of 4 lines, with different parameters for the executable I'm running and different output file names. I know each of these commands works, as if I type the exact command into the console, I can get it to run. However, if I run the script (which I've named Part1-1.sh), I get 3 "command not found" errors, followed by the line numbers 1:, 2:, and 3:

Comment: You need to make sure `$PATH` is defined before your script runs. You can check this by running `/usr/bin/env` using it's full path at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to know is the current location of your script, regardless of how it's called (either with an absolute path, a relative path, or via the shell's $PATH). Once you know that, you can then reference your other executable via a path relative to the current location.

You can get the current location of the running script with the following:

```
MYLOC=`dirname $0`
```

...and then run your relative executable using this variable:

```
$MYLOC/../filename
```

This works regardless of the current working directory (e.g. $pwd) and even works if your script is found and executed via the shell's $PATH... since, if the script is executed via an absolute or relative path, $0 has the associated value... or, if the script is execute by searching the shell's $PATH, then $0 contains the absolute, full path to the script file.

Comment: So, I've now also tried just running the script with only the first command '../filename {options} {parameters} &

Even in this case, I get ": command not found1:"

Including the following at the top of my shell file:

    MYLOC ='dirname $0'
    $MYLOC/../filename {options} {parameters}

I end up with the following error - "./Part1-1.sh: line 1: MYLOC: command not found
: command not found2:"

Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: Plese note: the `dirname $0` is in backquotes not single-quotes. The use of the backquote character (the unshifted tilde on most keyboards) will cause the contents to be replaced with the output of the enclosing command.  I believe its the same as $(command) but the backtick syntax is much older (and more general)

Answer (score -1):

You probably change the current working directory when you are using `../filename`. So, better is to use in your `script_file.sh` the following lines:

```
current_directory=$(pwd)
../filename {options} {parameters} &
cd $current_directory
../filename {options2} {parameters} &
cd $current_directory
../filename {options3} {parameters} &
cd $current_directory
../filename {options4} {parameters} &
```

This will give you for sure the expected result.

Comment: No, it does not work like that. Even if `../filename` changes directory, it is a subprocess, so the parent does not feel the difference.